# Difficulty using overflow-x

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I have some data that I want to display with using a table like structure using div. I'm writing this in vuejs and using bootstrap. So I have a main wrapper with b-container and then use b-row for each row and b-col for each cell. The problem is that depending on the data the table could be larger than the specified size of the b-cointainer. I have tried using overflow-x: scroll; to make the content be scrollable, but the extra cells just get pushed down under. I also tried using overflow-x on each row, but that made a scrollbar for each row. When looking at the documentation for overflow-x it says that it will make it scrollable when it goes out of the edge on either left or right side. Does this not work since it's the child element of the child that will go of the screen?

```
<b-container style="overflow-x: scroll;">
    <b-row>
        <b-col>
            Information
        </b-col>
        ...
    </b-row>
    ...
</b-container>
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? The scrollbar doesn't show up on the x axis on the container when the table is large?

Comment: the scrollbar shows up, but all elements that should end up being hidden by the scrollbar just get pushed down.

So if the table can have 10 cells on the x-axis and I have 15. Those 5 that should be hidden until I scroll just get pushed down under the row

Comment: have you tried adding `flex-wrap: nowrap` to your `row`? Bootstrap uses flexbox and it will wrap your elements by default